# Firefox showing proxy server error after downloading Nvidia driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia

I downloaded NVIDIA driver 390 for my 820m GPU but after selecting it over intel my WiFi connection is not working without VPN service on. i deleted my NVIDIA driver but nothing changed should i uninstall VPN.
I already tried changing Firefox connection setting from user proxy to no proxy but then i was showing server connection error.plz help & forgive my English.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494513/edit) your question and include error messages.